# Template constructor defined in the same header but outside the class is unidentified

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I know template class definitions should be defined in the header file. However, the constructor defined in the header but outside the class seems to be unnoticed by the compiler while the constructor defined inside the class works just fine. Am I missing something completely obvious?

**This works**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    template<typename T, 
             typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
    A(T t) {
        this->t = static_cast<double>(t);
    }

    double t;
};

int main() {
    A a(3);
    std::cout << a.t << '\n';
}
```

**This does not**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    template<typename T, typename> B(T t);

    double t;
};

template<typename T, 
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
B::B(T t) {
    this->t = static_cast<double>(t);
}

int main() {
    B b(3);
    std::cout << b.t << '\n';
}
```

saying

```
error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(int)'
     B b(3);
          ^
```

Comment: Yes, you forgot the = typename<std::enable_if .... > stuf int the declaration (inside the class)

Comment: No it should not. Right? I am doing a template specialization for template<typename T, typename> B(T). Besides, it complains "error: template parameter redefines default argument" if I put typename<std::enable_if .... > in the class declaration for B.

Comment: Well, even if you got this to work: If you only specialize (and not SFINAE the declaration too) then a user will probably end up with linker errors when the specialization criteria are not met, which is not great. I'd say SFINAE the declaration too.

Comment: OK but how do you SFINAE the declaration? The one suggested by Gojita does not work obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a few things.
The defaulted template argument should be in the class declaration.
And you'll need a typename added to that.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> B(T t);

    double t;
};

template<typename T,
    typename>
    B::B(T t) {
    this->t = static_cast<double>(t);
}

int main() {
    B b(3);
    std::cout << b.t << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. Thanks. However, the fact that clang does not break for my code is interesting .

Comment: Can you please explain why my code does not work? Or can you link me to a source or at least provide a keyword to search in google?

Comment: @Barry No, the definition of the constructor is out-of-line. That's also what I understood the question title (and content) to be about specifically.

Comment: @IsuraManchanayake
Pardon any bad lingo, I'm not a language lawyer.

Defaulted template parameters, e.g 'typename = xxx' can only be specified in the *declaration* and not the *definition*. The constructor you wrote in the class is the declaration and the definition is the one you defined further below. 

Also you need the extra typename because the compiler doesn't understand that 'std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type' resolves to a type because C++ is complicated to parse.

You could also use std::enable_if_t to make it shorter if that's available to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @vlind

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think this is just a gcc bug. Filed [88864](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88864).

This is a shorter reproduction that should compile but doesn't (clang accepts):

```
struct B {
    template<typename T, typename U> B(T t);
};

template <typename T, typename U = int>
B::B(T t) { }

B b(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug

Comment: Is adding default arguments after the declaration actually a thing? It's probably a separate question (because the details involve explaining the steps the compiler has to take) but I'm not sure what I'd expect from this code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, it is. `void foo(int, int=4); void foo(int=5, int); foo();` works and calls `foo(5,4)`